# how to make RabbitMQ in docker get messages when it is going to local RMQ

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, stomp

I have RabbitMQ Erlang 13.1.2 and RabbitMQ 3.11.2 installed in my local and I have  deployed a docker container with RabbitMQ instance runnning as well. I cant unistall / stop my local RabbitMQ as I dont have admin rights at the moment.

I am running a WebSocket SpringBoot App in which MessageBroker Rabbit is configured as follows

```
@Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config
            .setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
            .enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic")
            .setRelayHost("localhost")
            .setRelayPort(61613)
            .setClientLogin("admin")
            .setClientPasscode("admin");
    }
```

The Issue is When I change credentials to *guest* which is my local RMQ server. All the messages go to local RMQ server  and it works fine but when I change it to *admin* my docker RMQ  user it shows

```
<<< ERROR
message:Bad CONNECT
content-type:text/plain
version:1.0,1.1,1.2
content-length:32

Access refused for user 'admin'
```

both local and docker instance run on localhost with same ports exposed I dont know how to get messages sent to docker instance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to bind two network services on the same host to one port. One of them simply would not start. So you either forgot to publish RabbitMQ port when you started docker container, or container uses some other port. To start RabbitMQ docker container, exposing a port you should use `--publish / -p` option of the `docker run` command:

```
docker run -d --hostname rmq --name some-rabbit -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3
```

In this example RabbitMQ instance, running inside docker, will be available on the host through default ports. See [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) for the additional info.

Comment: I have published the ports     ```  docker container run -it --name rabbitmq-stomp -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 -p 61613:61613 pcloud/rabbitmq-stom ```  use this command is there any way I can run my docker on different ports

Comment: If you want RabbitMQ on host port 61613 you should use command `docker run -d --hostname rmq --name some-rabbit -p 61613:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3`